# JQuery UI Datepicker Disable Month on Select

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have a datepicker assigned to several fields with an array of specific dates already disabled in my beforeShowDay attribute.

```
.datepicker({ beforeShowDay: disablePaymentDates, minDate: 0, maxDate: afterSixMonths });
```

I'm attempting to disable the month of the date the user selects across all datepickers. Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: What's "disablePaymentDates"? an array ? it should be a function with date as parameter.  http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShowDay

Comment: Its an array holding dates in mm/dd format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a solution similar to Roetnig's. I added the following code to the function the beforeShowDay attribute calls.

```
var monthsToDisable= [];
if ($.inArray(date.getMonth(date), monthsToDisable) > -1) {
    $return = false;
    $returnclass = "unavailable";
}
```

I then populate the 'monthsToDisable' with the appropriate months (0-11). Since this array will be updated based on the user action I just had to simply reapply the datepicker after updating the array.

Answer (score 1):

As indicated in the [datepicker API](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShowDay):

**beforeShowDay**

Type: Function( Date date )

Default: null

A function that takes a date as a parameter and must return an array with:

**[0]**: true/false indicating whether or not this date is selectable **[1]**: a CSS class name to add to the date's cell or "" for the default presentation  **[2]**: an optional popup tooltip for this date

The function is called for each day in the datepicker before it is displayed.

```
.datepicker({
    minDate: 0, 
    maxDate: afterSixMonths,
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
        var dd = date.getDate();
        if ($.inArray( dd, disablePaymentDates)!= -1) {
            return [false, "", "disabled" ];
        } else {
            return [true, "", "enabled" ];
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: So would I have to reapply the date picker to all elements in order to disable the month when a date is chosen?

Comment: You may add whatever you want inside the function... disable certain days of the week, the current month, whatever. You receive the date in the function, check for validity, and return the three values. This was just an example of use.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can disable date range with using moment.js

```
var disableRangeStartDate = '2017-10-29';
var disableRangeEndDate = '2018-04-18';

.datepicker({
isInvalidDate: function(arg){
      var thisMonth = arg._d.getMonth()+1;
      if (thisMonth<10){thisMonth = "0"+thisMonth;}
      var thisDate = arg._d.getDate();
      if (thisDate<10){thisDate = "0"+thisDate;}
      var thisYear = arg._d.getYear()+1900;
      var thisCompare = thisYear +"-"+ thisMonth +"-"+ thisDate;

     return moment(thisCompare).isBetween(disableRangeStartDate, disableRangeEndDate);
      }
});
```